# two seemingly identical PHP echo blocks, one doesn't work?

Tags: php, json, echo, server-sent-events

I have two seemingly identical chunks of code. With the first one, the client-side file (using a Server Sent Event connection) can properly receive and display JSON data, while with the other code it can't. I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Here's the first, **working code**:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

function sendMsg($id , $msg) {
  echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: {\n";
  echo "data: \"name\": \"Bob\", \n";
  echo "data: \"msg\": \"$msg\", \n";
  echo "data: \"id\": $id\n";
  echo "data: }\n";
  echo PHP_EOL;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}

sendMsg(1, 'hello');
```

In the client-side file, data.name will display "Bob" and data.msg will display "hello".

This is the **non-working code**:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$out .= "id: 1" . PHP_EOL;
$out .= "data: {\n";
$out .= "data: \"name\": \"Bob\",\n";
$out .= "data: \"msg\": \"hello\", \n";
$out .= "data: }\n";
$out .= PHP_EOL;
echo $out;
ob_flush();
flush();
```

It seems exactly the same to me but nothing will display! What gives? I've even tried translating the non-working code to use all "echo" statements, instead of `.out =`, so that it was near-identical to the first.... does anyone see an error/difference?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you forgot to initialize `$out = '';` in the beginning. check if you are getting PHP warning?

Comment: How are these identical? Anyway, what does PHP error log show for the non-working one?

Comment: `$out` - variable was not initialised.

Comment: don't try to hand code json. try using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: PHP syntax wise there is nothing wrong with this code

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ, except it will generate a PHP warning on the first `$out .=` line if error reporting is enabled for warnings

Comment: @bansi do you recommend I just code an array first and then use json_econde() on the array?

Comment: @james how do I pull up a PHP error log? the PHP error log under my WAMP server displays nothing. .. I never was able to figure out php debugging

Comment: yes I strongly recommend ` json_econde`. you can always mess very easily if you hand code json objects. and it is going to be a nightmare later

Comment: @bansi but is writing an `array` the way to do it?

Comment: array is easier. you can also encode objects with json_encode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example, the JSON string you are sending out has a dangling comma at the end of it, which isn't valid.

You're sending:

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "msg": "hello",
}                 ^---Right there
```